# how can i use ref.read in initstate?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
 import 'package:enue/community/gyeongin/addposting/add_posting.dart';
 import 'package:enue/provider/posting/posting_provider.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

 class PostingHome extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
   const PostingHome({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _PostingHomeState();
}

 class _PostingHomeState extends ConsumerState<PostingHome> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return const AddPosting();
          },
        ),
      );
    },
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc54245),
    child: const Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.white),
  ),
  body: Consumer(
    builder: (context, ref, widget) {
      final postingHomeState = ref.watch(postingHomeProvider);

      return ListView.builder(
        controller: postingHomeState.scrollController,
        itemCount: postingHomeState.list.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < postingHomeState.list.length) {
            final item = postingHomeState.list[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item['title']),
              subtitle: Text(item['subtitle']),
            );
          } else if (postingHomeState.isMore) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

this is my viewpage
and i'm trying pagination using riverpod
and my riverpod class is at under
as you can see, i need to call init() function in my viewpage but i can't call init() function in my consumersatefulwidget becuase the error says "Unhandled Exception: Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building."
how can i success pagination !! please help me bro!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final postingHomeProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<
    PostingHomeStateNotifier,
    PostingHomeState>((ref) => PostingHomeStateNotifier());

class PostingHomeState {
  const PostingHomeState({
    this.isMore = true,
    this.isLoading = false,
    this.list = const [],
    required this.scrollController,
  });

  final bool isMore;
  final bool isLoading;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> list;
  final ScrollController scrollController;

  PostingHomeState copyWith({
    bool? isMore,
    bool? isLoading,
    List<Map<String, dynamic>>? list,
    ScrollController? scrollController,
  }) {
    return PostingHomeState(
      isMore: isMore ?? this.isMore,
      isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
      list: list ?? this.list,
      scrollController: scrollController ?? this.scrollController,
     );
  }
}

class PostingHomeStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<PostingHomeState> {
  PostingHomeStateNotifier()
      : super(PostingHomeState(
            scrollController: ScrollController(),
            list: const [],
            isLoading: false,
            isMore: true));

  DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument;

  Future<void> paginatedData() async {
    if (state.isMore) {
      state = state.copyWith(isLoading: true);
      final collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("경인교대(게시글)")
          .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true);

      late QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot;

      if (lastDocument == null) {
        querySnapshot = await collectionReference.limit(10).get();
      } else {
        querySnapshot = await collectionReference
            .limit(10)
            .startAfterDocument(lastDocument!)
            .get();
      }

      lastDocument =
          querySnapshot.docs.isEmpty ? null : querySnapshot.docs.last;

      state = state.copyWith(
          list: [...state.list, ...querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data())],
          isLoading: false);

      if (querySnapshot.docs.length < 10) {
        state = state.copyWith(isMore: false);
      }
    }
  }

  void onScroll() {
    if (state.scrollController.position.pixels ==
        state.scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      paginatedData();
    }
  }

  void init() {
    paginatedData();
    state.scrollController.addListener(onScroll);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    state.scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
final myData = Provider<int>((_) => 42);

class RiverpodDemo extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RiverpodDemo({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<RiverpodDemo> createState() => _RiverpodExampleState();
}

class _RiverpodExampleState extends ConsumerState<RiverpodDemo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final value = ref.read(myData);
    print(value); // 42
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = ref.watch(myData);
    return Text('$value'); // 42
  }
}
```

use this example as a guide